# Memory leak while sending response from rebus handler

Tags: rebus

I saw a very strange behavior in my rebus handler which is self hosted in exe. Right after sending response using bus.send method it adds up some memory consumed by process. I tried to look up object graph using memory profile and found that rebus is holding response message in serialized format somewhere. 
Object graph was showing below hierarchy to the root.
System.Message -->  CachedBodyMessage  -->  stream

Give me some pointers if anybody is aware of this thing.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that a memory leak is a grave concern, but my belief is that it is unlikely that Rebus should contain a memory leak.

This belief is rooted in the fact that I have been running Windows Service-hosted Rebus endpoints in production for 1,5 years now, and several of them (e.g. the timeout managers) have sometimes been running for several months without being restarted.

I'd like to be absolutely bulletproof sure though, so I'm willing to investigate the issue you're reporting.

You're mentioning "CachedBodyMessage" - judging by the names of fields inside System.Messaging.Message, it sounds like it's something within MSMQ. To try to reproduce your issue, I coded the following test:

```
[Test, Ignore("Only works in RELEASE mode because otherwise object references are held on to for the duration of the method")]
public void DoesNotLeakMessages()
{
    // arrange
    const string inputQueueName = "test.leak.input";
    var queue = new MsmqMessageQueue(inputQueueName);
    disposables.Add(queue);

    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new string('*', 32768));
    var message = new TransportMessageToSend
                    {
                        Headers = new Dictionary<string, object> { { Headers.MessageId, "msg-1" } },
                        Body = body
                    };

    var weakMessageRef = new WeakReference(message);
    var weakBodyRef = new WeakReference(body);


    // act
    queue.Send(inputQueueName, message, new NoTransaction());
    message = null;
    body = null;

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    // assert
    Assert.That(weakMessageRef.IsAlive, Is.False, "Expected the message to have been collected");
    Assert.That(weakBodyRef.IsAlive, Is.False, "Expected the body bytes to have been collected");
}
```

which verifies that the sent transport message is collected as it should (will only do this in RELEASE mode though, because of the way DEBUG mode holds on to object references within scope)

I'll try and run the TimePrinter sample now and leave it running for a while to see if I can reproduce the issue. If you stumble upon more information about e.g. exactly which objects are leaking, it would be very helpful.

Thanks again for taking the time to report your worries to me :)

*Followup:*

I've modified the TimePrinter sample so that it sends 50 msg/s and includes a 64 KB random string payload with each message, and I've tracked the memory usage for almost four hours now. As you can see, it does not look like memory is being leaked.

[image: Perfmon memory trace]

I'll leave it running the rest of the day, just to be sure.

Maybe you can tell me some more about why you suspected there was a memory leak in the first place?

*Update:*

As you can see from the trace, it has now been running for 7 hours and thus more than 1,200,000 messages containing more than 70 GB of data has been sent and consumed by the same process. If cached message bodies were leaking, I am pretty sure that we would have been able to see something rising on the graph.

[image: Perfmon memory trace 2]